# Override a Page Filter Using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a page filter that I'm trying to override using the ALL function. I want to display all occurrences where 'BDD conso' is less than 0, regardless of the page filter. I've been trying to add ALL(month) to my measure, but without success.
Thank you for your help !
[Here is the link of my file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv6nJHKkOozzB3YZ5p?e=dccmnO)

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Certainly Davide ! I will !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page filters cannot be overridden.